# Extract n words from string using Perl

Tags: perl

i have a text containing sentences in each line, and in front of each word its lemmetize form exemple:

he "he" went "go" to "to" school "school" with "with" his "his" freinds "freind"

i would like to extract for example three by three word in in each line. The result seems like this:

he "he" went "go" to "to" \n
went "go" to "to" school "school" \n
to "to" school "school" with "with" \n
school "school" with "with" his "his" \n
with "with" his "his" freinds "freind" \n

I'd like to do this using Perl.

Comment: What you are looking for is n-grams. Google "n-grams Perl" and you will find many ways to do this, including modules on CPAN.

Comment: you go throw the file. For each line, you split it by the *space* character. 
`for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i+=2) 
{
    // first word
    print(array[i]);
    print(array[i+1]);
    // second word
    print(array[i+2]);
    print(array[i+3]);
    // third word
    print(array[i+4]);
    print(array[i+5]);
}`
I let you check the corner cases (array not empty...)

Comment: So where's your code? What have you tried?

Comment: The data that you provide is not the same data that you show in the expected result. "`with "with" his "his"`" is repeated on the last and second-to-last lines.

Answer (score 0):

thank you all for your helps, i found a solution, it works, but it's in dirty code i think, that's why i asked this question, to find a better solution, the awk solution seems great but the result not like i look,

This is the solution i fixed the window at 7 words and in front of each word it's POS and it's lemmetized form: 
he "he" "PRO" went "go" "V" to "to" "PREP" school "school" "N" ...

```
open(F,"/home/file.txt")||die "error";

my $string;

while($ligne = <F> ) {

my @val = split(/ /, $ligne);
my $long=$#val;

for($i=0; $i<$long;$i+=3){  


$string="$val[$i] $val[$i+1] $val[$i+2] $val[$i+3] $val[$i+4] $val[$i+5] $val[$i+6] $val[$i+7] $val[$i+8] $val[$i+9] $val[$i+10] $val[$i+11] $val[$i+12] $val[$i+13] $val[$i+14] $val[$i+15] $val[$i+16] $val[$i+17] $val[$i+18] $val[$i+19] $val[$i+20]";

my @val2 = split(/ /, $string);
my $long2=$#val2;
if($long2 >19){ #if length superior at 19, (3*7)
print FILEOUT "$string\n";
$string="";
}

       }

}
```

Comment: You may accept your own answer. https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/

Answer (score 0):

This script starts by reading the entire line as an array of words (@words) and then uses an @aux array as a FIFO... discarding the first 2 elements at each pass and keeping the FIFO size always 6 itens... then, reapeat while there are words in the @words array:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

my $file = 'file.txt';
open(F,$file)||die "error";
my @aux;
while(<F>) {
  my @words = split /\s+/;
  while($#words >= 0) {
    while($#aux < 5 && $#words >= 0) {
      my $a = shift @words;
      push @aux, $a;
    }
    print ((join " ", @aux)."\n");
    shift @aux;
    shift @aux;
  }
}
```